# manifest multiple problems the activity element must be a direct child

Tags: java, android

i have added a splash screen but now i'm facing multiple problems saying for the first
-the activity element must be a direct child for the application element

i wish you can help me this is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="imamalsajadsayings.android.com"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/splashScreenTheme" />    
    <activity
        android:name="imamalsajadsayings.android.com.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: You closed your <application> tag before the <activity> tag.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `/` from application tag, replace application with below

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/splashScreenTheme" >
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove / from application tag

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/splashScreenTheme" />
```

to

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/splashScreenTheme" >
```